# How to put two Ext.Panels to the left and right of each other in another Ext.Panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to create a layout in ExtJS which has a grid on top and on the bottom left and right sections, a basic parent/child, master/details layout:

```
wrapper_panel
panel_top
  [grid]
panel_bottom
  [left_area     right_area]
```

However, the two areas in `panel_bottom` are on top of each other instead of to the left and right

```
var left_area = new Ext.Panel({
    region: 'west',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 100,
    items: []
});

var right_area = new Ext.Panel({
    region: 'center',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 100,
    items: []
});


var panel_bottom = new Ext.Panel({
    //layout: 'border',
    region: 'south',
    items: [ left_area, right_area ]
})
```

It looks like this:

[image]

If I make the panel_bottom `layout: border` then the left and right areas disappear completely.

**What do I need to change in the bottom area panels so that they line up left and right?**

## Addendum

@vimvds, if I add `width: 200` or e.g. `width: 300`, I just get this:

[image]

Thanks for the answers, it led me to scrap this and use the `table` layout instead, which led me to another question [how to define percentage instead of absolute values for height/width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968303/how-to-make-an-extjs-table-layout-have-percentage-instead-of-abolute-values-for-h).

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a [`Ext.layout.HBoxLayout`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.HBoxLayout):

```
var panel_bottom = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    defaults: {
        flex: 1
    },
    items: [ left_area, right_area ],
});
```

Alternatively you could also use a [`Ext.layout.TableLayout`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.TableLayout) or a [`Ext.layout.ColumnLayout`](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.layout.ColumnLayout):

```
var panel_bottom = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'column',
    defaults: {
        columnWidth: 0.5
    },
    items: [ left_area, right_area ],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

And what happens if you use :

```
var panel_bottom = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'border',
    items: [ left_area, right_area ],
    width: 200
});
```

Comment: it just extends the area to the right in which they *could* line up horizontally, but they remain stacked vertically, see above

Comment: Hmm, weird, I don't have that problem, though I specified a fixed height on the container (your panel_bottom). We used a rowexpander to show the details in a master/detail grid.

Comment: try 'column' layout, to make sure add widths as "columnWidth: .50" on each panels to split evenly