# How to make an ExtJS table layout have percentage instead of absolute values for height and width?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using `Ext.Panel` and the `table` layout, I was able to create a layout just the way I want. However, **how do I change this code so that I can define the widths and heights proportionally?**

e.g. the table should not be 800 pixels but 100% of the screen width, and each box not 200 pixels but 25%.

[image]

here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    clearExtjsComponent(targetRegion);

    var table_wrapper2 = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'table_wrapper2',
        baseCls: 'x-plain',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout:'table',
        layoutConfig: {columns:2},
        defaults: {
            frame:true,
            width:200,
            height: 200,
            style: 'margin: 0 10px 10px 0'
        },
        items:[{
                title:'Shopping Cart',
                width: 400,
                height: 290,
                colspan: 2
            },{
                title:'Invoice Address',
                width: 190,
                height: 100
            },{
                title:'Delivery Address',
                width: 200,
                height: 100
            }
        ]
    })

    var table_wrapper = new Ext.Panel({
        id:'table_wrapper',
        baseCls:'x-plain',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout:'table',
        layoutConfig: {columns:4},
        defaults: {
            frame:true,
            width:200,
            height: 200,
            style: 'margin: 10px 0 0 10px'
        },
        items:[{
                title:'Orders',
                width: 810,
                colspan: 4
            },{
                title:'Customer Information',
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                colspan: 2
            },{
                //title:'Shopping Cart',
                frame: false,
                border: false,
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                colspan: 2,
                items: [ table_wrapper2 ]
            }
        ]
    });

    replaceComponentContent(targetRegion, table_wrapper);

    hideComponent(regionHelp);

</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of :

```
    layout:'table',
    layoutConfig: {columns:2},
```

try this :

```
    layout: {
       type: 'table',
       columns: 3,
       tableAttrs: {
          style: {
             width: '100%',
             height: '100%'
          }
       }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the reply to your other thread using vbox and hbox layouts might be a little easier for you if you want to do relative positioning. Also, if you want to stretch things to your window, put it in a Viewport, that automatically uses you entire window.

You might want to change the layout a bit (borders, frames), but with vbox and hbox layouts it would be something like this:

```
new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'vbox',
    layoutConfig: {
        align : 'stretch',
        pack  : 'start'
    },
    defaults: {
        style: 'margin: 10px 0 0 10px'
    },
    items:[{
            title:'Orders',
            height: 200
        },{
            layout: 'hbox',
            flex: 1,
            layoutConfig: {
                align : 'stretch',
                pack  : 'start'
            },
            items: [{
                title:'Customer Information',
                flex: 1
            },{
                layout: 'vbox',
                flex: 1,
                layoutConfig: {
                    align : 'stretch',
                    pack  : 'start'
                },
                items: [{
                    title: 'Shopping cart',
                    height: 200
                },{
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    layoutConfig: {
                        align : 'stretch',
                        pack  : 'start'
                    },
                    items: [{
                        title: 'Invoice address',
                        flex: 1
                    },{
                        title: 'Delivery address',
                        flex: 1
                    }]
                }]
            }]

        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one fiddle example :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2dm

```
Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    title: 'Car Simple Tree',
    height: 200, //Fixed height for this panel
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        columns: 2,
        tableAttrs: {
            style: {
                width: '100%' // To make the cell width 100% 
            }
        }
    },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        title: 'panel title',
        collapsible: true,
        titleCollapse: true,
        bodyStyle: {
            background: '#D9E5F3',
            borderColor: '#99BCE8',
            borderWidth: '1px'
        },
        //scrollable: true,
        //autoScroll: true,
        layout: {
            pack: 'center',
            type: 'hbox'
        },
        rowspan: 1,
        colspan: 2,
        width: '100%',
        items: [{
            text: 'Save',
            xtype: 'button',
            padding: 5
        }]
    }, {
        html: 'Cell C content',
        cellCls: 'highlight'
    }, {
        html: 'Cell D content'
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `ColumnLayout` instead. This gives you a choice between pixels and percentages for widths.